# How to pass variables at run time to graphql requests

Tags: jmeter

1. I am designing a Jmeter script which has graphQL type HTTP request.
2. One of the graphQL requests accepts a user defined type as an input parameter.
3. In Jmeter I created a graphQL type HTTP request. In the query section I added the query and in the variables section I added the variable.
4. The issue is the variable section accepts some data at run time. Say userId, which I already defined in the user defined variables section. Say userId - 100, is defined in that section.
5. Say suppose the variables is of this type:
   {
   "users" : {

"userId" : "100",
"date" : "2021-08-23T10:12:13:666666"
}
}

6. In this case how do I pass userId at run time ?
7. And I have a bean shell pre-processor in which I have generated the current date time and stored that in a string variable. How do I pass that string variable at run time in this body.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your GraphQL contract/query it is quite hard or even impossible to come up with a comprehensive answer.

If you want to parameterize your GraphQL query you need to remember that [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) syntax conflicts with [GraphQL variables](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/) syntax, that's why `GraphQL HTTP Request` has "Variables" section

[image]

Given the [following example GraphQL server](https://github.com/apollographql/starwars-server): you can request a droid with ID of `2000` details using the next query:

```
query {
  droid(id: 2000){
    id
    name
    friends{
      name
    }
    appearsIn
    primaryFunction
  }
}
```

and it will work:

[image]

---

However if you need to make this id of `2000` dynamic you will need to take some extra steps, like in variables section put the following JSON:

```
{
  "id": "2000"
}
```

or if you want to parameterize it with User Defined Variables you can use the JMeter Variable reference here:

```
{
  "id": "${id}"
}
```

and amend your query to look like:

```
query ($id: ID!){
  droid(id: $id){
    id
    name
    friends{
      name
    }
    appearsIn
    primaryFunction
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Introducing JMeter 5.4: New Features and Abilities](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your response. This is how the query looks like:

query($users: UserDetailsInput) {
 calculateOrder(userDetails: $users) {

  /* OTHER ATTRIBUTES HERE */

 }
}

And this is the variable that we need to send along with the request :
{
 "users": {
  "userId": "100",
  "date": "2021-08-24T13:11:56",
 
 }
}

In this please note that userId and date are dynamic. In order to fetch userId a bean shell pre-processor was written in which userId is stored in a hashmap and date is generated and stored in a string variable in same bean shell pre processor.